# Why is $z$ used as the independent variable symbol for some functions?

Tags: complex-numbers, notation

I've recently taken a great interest in the hyperbolic trigonometric functions and hyperbolic geometry in general and I've noticed that some definitions for the hyperbolic trigonometric functions involve "$z$" as the independent variable symbol instead of the standard "$x$" used in lower mathematics. Why? Here, take a look at Wolfram's definition for $\tanh$:
$$
\begin{align}
\tanh(z)=&\frac{\sinh(z)}{\cosh(z)}\\
       =&\frac{e^z-e^{-z}}{e^z+e^{-z}}\\
       =&\frac{e^{2z}-1}{e^{2z}+1}
\end{align}\\
$$
(Source: [Wolfram MathWorld: Hyperbolic Tangent](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HyperbolicTangent.html))

This by no means seems to be the standard as Wikipedia uses the same definition but with an "$x$" instead of a "$z$". (Source: [Wikipedia: Hyperbolic Functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_functions#Exponential_definitions)) Perhaps this redefinition on Wolfram's part is merely a stylistic choice, after all, I am no mathematician. My personal theory is that the "$z$" denotes some relation to complex numbers or its complex graph as I sometimes see "$z$" used in those sorts of places. Are there specific guidelines or am I being quite silly and pedantic?

Comment: No particular reason here... but $z$ is often used for complex variables ($z = x + i y$) so perhaps with the complex definitions of $\sinh$ and $\cosh$ they are simply preparing you.  Don't worry about this.  (Yep... just a bit silly and pedantic...)

Comment: Okay, thank you kind sir! I appreciate it. What exactly do you mean about "preparing you?" Would this prepare the reader for further complex operations to follow, for example, if I used z instead of x while analyzing a complex graph?

Comment: By "preparing you" I mean that your teachers and books are likely using a single symbol ($z$) that actually represents a *two*-dimensional mathematical entity ($x + i y$).  It is the same type of "preparation" you get when you use a single symbol (e.g., ${\bf a}$) that will ultimately represent $n$ components of a vector ($a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n$).  This is a general trend in mathematical notation as you learn more.  For example:  ${\bf A}$ could represent a *matrix* containing $n \times d$ individual elements.  And get ready... someday you'll hit *tensors*, representing $n \times d \times ...$

Comment: Alrighty thank you, David!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is often used as a notation for a complex number $x + i y$. Other than the common use of letters near the end of the alphabet, the names of variables are pretty arbitrary.